How do these two ways of creating an S4 object differ?
I have seen instances of each of these in various packages.
1)
foo <- setClass('foo',[slots defined])
bar <- foo([data ]) 

or
2)
setClass('foo',[slots defined])
bar <- new('foo',[data])

Is there any difference in performance, or in the material which would be required in a NAMESPACE file?

This doesn't relate to performance but style. In Advanced R, Hadley Wickham writes, new() is a low-level constructor suitable for use by you, the developer. User-facing classes should always be paired with a user-friendly helper

@SamR if you'd like to turn that into an answer, I'll select it

Thanks but I don't know if I have enough to say. Hadley Wickham is obviously an authoritative source in the R world but it's still an opinion. It's a good question and I would like to know if there are any technical differences. I was hoping someone with more expertise would answer,

@SamR This is an incorrect interpretation of the text. He says that you should create user-facing function to make classes instead of relying on the stock S4 ones and treat the stock S4 ones (or really, any other ones) as a low-level ones.

@Colombo how is that different to what I wrote?

@SamR I assumed that you are writing your response to said question that was asking about the difference between foo = setClass("foo", ...); foo() and `setClass("foo", ...); new()". If you were just making a general comment about constructors then yes, you are right.

They are identical.
Your foo(...) is calling new("foo", ...)
The obvious difference is that with new() you don't need to have the object/function foo() to define a new instance of class "foo".

Fist breadcrumb:
# slots or something need to be defined
# otherwise we would get error during instantiation

foo = setClass("foo", slots = c(x = "numeric"))
foo
# class generator function for class “foo” from package ‘.GlobalEnv’
# function (...) 
# new("foo", ...)

So foo returns a function new("foo", ...)?
A few more things don't lead anywhere:
fo = unclass(foo)
is(fo)
# [1] "function"         "OptionalFunction" "PossibleMethod"  
print(fo)
# <S4 object of class NULL>
# attr(,"className")
# [1] "foo"
# attr(,"className")attr(,"package")
# [1] ".GlobalEnv"
# attr(,"package")
# [1] ".GlobalEnv"

Instead of continuing there, I just looked at the code for:
class(foo)
# [1] "classGeneratorFunction"
# attr(,"package")
# [1] "methods"

Obviously, setClass returns an object of classGeneratorFunction:
setClass <-
    ...
    invisible(classGeneratorFunction(classDef, where))

But I would like to point at following lines:
https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/4aa0fbba136591d6e7744fab83d722b5a5e5c690/src/library/methods/R/SClasses.R#L944-L972
specifically: https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/4aa0fbba136591d6e7744fab83d722b5a5e5c690/src/library/methods/R/SClasses.R#L947-L948
    body(fun) <- substitute(new(CLASS, ...),
                            list(CLASS = classDef@className))

